# Asp.net Button event firing with jquery code

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Div_1").show();
    $("#Div_2").hide();
    $('#Button1').click(function () {
        $("#Div_1").hide();
       $("#Div_2").show();
       return false;
    });
});
```

> ```
> protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         Label1.Text = "Rajesh Gonugunta";
>     }
> ```
>
> in the above code jquery code is working fine but event is not firing

Comment: is the button placed inside an UpdatePanel?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `return false` (and/or replace it with `return true`). Because your browser will cancel the button click event if you return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `return false;` statement.

Return false will return immediately instead of going to the server.

```
$("#Div_1").show();
$("#Div_2").hide();

$('#Button1').click(function () {

    $("#Div_1").hide();
    $("#Div_2").show();
});
```

---

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "Rajesh Gonugunta";
}
```